# Deleting MySQL partial matches

Tags: mysql, filter, duplicates, partial

I have a MySQL table of auto-generated tags, and I'm wanting to delete any shorter tags that appear within longer tags.

For example, say `SELECT * FROM tags` returns

```
Donald Trump
Donald
Trump
Hillary Clinton
Hillary
Clinton
US Election
US
Election
```

I'm wanting to delete any shorter tags that appear within longer tags, so I end up with:

```
Donald Trump
Hillary Clinton
US Election
```

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Join the table with itself, and delete the rows with shorter names that can be found inside the longer name.

```
DELETE t1
FROM tags AS t1
JOIN tags AS t2 ON LENGTH(t1.name) < LENGTH(t2.name) AND LOCATE(t1.name, t2.name)
```